# merge two xml using grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-jsbeautifier

how to merge two xml files using grunt.

I need to merge two xml files

**A.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<module id="one">
<a>numberone</a>
</module>
```

**B.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<module id="two">
<a>numbertwo</a>
</module>
```

after merging the xml will be like following
**c.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<module id="one">
<a>numberone</a>
</module>
<module id="two">
<a>numbertwo</a>
</module>
```

Comment: since there is no xml merge plugin in grunt, you have to do manually. concat xmls,  remove xml node and write the banner

Comment: Possible (late) answer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-concat-language